# IOS Facebook SDK - Post Open Graph and show on Timeline without clicking Activity Log

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-ios-sdk

From the Facebook SDK sample code, when successfully posting the open graph object to the timeline, you have to click **Show on Timeline** in the **Activity Log** on the Facebook website.

How to ignore these steps and explicitly share your OG to timeline?

Answer (score 1):

I've moved this answer out of @isaacselement question.

---

Just add one more code to your **FBOpenGraphAction** Object:

```
id<FBOpenGraphAction> action = (id<FBOpenGraphAction>) [FBGraphObject graphObject];
[action setObject: @"true" forKey: @"fb:explicitly_shared"];  // This is the key point!
```

And you should enable the **'explicitly shared'** setting for the open graph action in the **Facebook Developer App Dashboard** in the website.

For more details, look at the [Document about Explicit Sharing](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/explicit-sharing/)

Answer (score -8):

You can use Scocial.framework for to directy post on facebook.
It just use users built in facebook account associated with ios.
And you will be able to post on timeline.

Comment: Posts and stories are two completely different things.