# Facebook iOS SDK: scrumptious facebook not posting to Facebook

Tags: ios, facebook

I just downloaded the latest iOS SDK from Facebook and managed to run the Scrumptious app successfully. I could post and received a successful post message within the app. But when I checked my Facebook page, I do not see the post on my timeline/wall. Is that normal?

I would think I will be able to see the post so that I can edit accordingly.

Anyone has this problem / any solutions?

Facebook iOS SDK: https://developers.facebook.com/ios/

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here:
[IOS Facebook SDK - Post Open Graph and show on Timeline without clicking Activity Log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17310892/ios-facebook-sdk-post-open-graph-and-show-on-timeline-without-clicking-activit)

Gotta specify fb:explicitly_share in the action object and explicitly set the privileges under Open Graph->action type in your Facebook App Open Graph settings.